# iOS Check every 5 minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an app that creates messages that are then sent up to a host server.

The app has to be able to work entirely offline and so when the messages are created (and stored into CoreData) they are set as "unsent". The app then tries to send them instantly. If there is a connection and the server response is positive then I set the message to "sent".

Of course, this means that if the phone is offline when the message is created then it will never be sent.

All my messages are sent through a singleton object that manages all the message sending and queueing.

I have tried to put an NSTimer into the init of the singleton that triggers the send every 5 minutes (changed to 10 seconds for testing). This works fine until I stop the app for longer than the period of the NSTimer.

If I stop the app for 30 seconds then restart it again then the timer doesn't trigger.

Is there a better way of doing this so that I get the same functionality? i.e. check every few mins for outgoing messages and send any that are waiting.

**EDIT**

I'm not invalidating the timer or anything. It's just that if the app is not active when the timer is due to fire then it seems to not schedule it again.

The code for my `NSTimer` is...

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(sendMessages) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

If I put the app to the background and then make it active before the timer is due to fire then it will continue to run with no problems. But if I put the app to the background and then wait 30 then when I go back to the app the timer never fires again.

Comment: I don't understand what is stopping your timer from triggering. Can you post some code where you have setup your timer and also code were you release it or invalidate it or something? Thankyou!

Comment: Code added to explain timer problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could listen to these `NSNotifications` and simply invalidate and restore the timer when the app leaves and enters the running state:

```
UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
```

Also make sure that the property of the `NSTimer` is `strong` so that the timer doesn't get released.

```
@property (strong) NSTimer *timer;
```

Another way of solving your issue would be using a 3rd-party queuing class or library. For example [IFOfflineQueue](https://github.com/marcoarment/IPOfflineQueue).

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of doing that! I think I'll give it a go using the notifications.

Comment: Or you can simply start your timer again in -viewDidAppear

Comment: I tried this method and got some odd results. Turns out all I needed to do was store the timer as a strong property of the singleton when I scheduled it. If you edit your answer to add this I'll accept :D as you helped me find the answer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "Strong property" I've only used it once a long time ago because a tutorial said to... hehe... anyways does that force the timer to stay active in the background? If so your app may hog processing power and/or drain the device's battery when left on. If not that I'm glad you got an answer :) Best of luck!

Comment: I guess the timer get's released if you don't keep a strong reference to it.